# Move apps to SD card at once

Tags: applications, external-sd, insufficient-memory, lg

My LG phone's internal storage is full, the phone is NOT rooted.

I know I can move apps to SD card one by one: |cog icon| Apps | tap each app one by one and pray for the Move button to appear, but this is too time-consuming.

I recall I saw a place where all apps were listed and a checkbox was next to those apps that supported moving to SD card, so I could [X] check all boxes and tap one big Move button to move all those apps at once instead of guessing one by one which one can be moved. How do I do that?

After Googling around a lot,  I found [this page](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/move-android-apps-sd-card/#:%7E:text=To%20move%20more%20than%20one,or%20Move%20to%20SD%20card.), but I cannot find the menu it talks about and cannot find any Multi-select option. I also cannot find the Settings app they mention. In addition, their method seems to require the phone to be rooted. How can I do the same -- multi-select the apps and move them to the SD card all at once? (what would also help is a list of all apps on my phone that support moving to an SD card)